# How to give jump animation to UIButton?

Tags: iphone, animation, uibutton

I want to jump `UIButton` when it's y position is <100.Jump animation is like that whenever button is dragged and reach to  y position is less than 100 then it will jump 3 times and it's new position is randomly on the screen.

Thnx in advance:-)

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you have a problem? This isn't a code-on-demand service.

Comment: actually i have no idea how to do that so i want advice for this my friend:-)

Comment: i got it using CATransaction and CAKeyFrameanimation.It works fine